# How to reinstall Windows 10 when you messed up?

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, reboot, asus-laptop, start-screen

Since i cannot remember the Windows 10 password, i decided to do a full reinstall on my Asus laptop.

At 26% iI get a message the reinstall is canceled. I thought they failure may be because the laptop wasn't connected to WiFi, so I chose to return to Windows so i could activate the network and then reboot again. That led to a new problem...

The screen just restarts itself at Asus, lights up - shows Asus - screen goes black - lights up - shows Asus - screen goes Black. And so on and on, neither F8 or F11 work, as it just pauses the launch of the Asus screen and goes into a black screen...

How would I troubleshoot this Windows install problem?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me. *"Since i couldnt remember my password i decided to do a full reboot of my Asus laptop."*  Do you mean you decided to do a clean reinstall of windows?

Comment: Yes, yes i did. Sorry for not expressing myself properly

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - With Windows 10, if the computer has had Windows 10 installed **and activated**, you **don't** need a license key. You can even click "don't have a license key" when conducting a clean installation. Activation of Windows 10 involves the Microsoft servers having a record of parts of your computer for security reasons. It uses that information to determine if you have had a license in the past and automatically reactivates Windows 10 when the info matches.  That's why you need a new license if you change the motherboard in your computer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're installing from a USB stick, I would try making sure your hard drive is fully formated before proceeding with the install. Else it may be trying to reinstall over your existing system.

When you get prompted on which partition you want to install, click on advanced then select and delete all partitions. When all partitions are deleted, select free space and click next (the Windows installer will do the partitioning for you).

If you're using your system's recovery to re-install, you might need access to a formattable USB drive (of at least 8GB) and another system with Windows 10. Then download the Windows media creation tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and use it to create a bootable Windows installer on your USB drive. Then on your laptop boot from the USB and make sure you delete all your partitions as mentioned above.